# Combine results from two queries. Must sort before using union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to combine the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [DATE] FROM [database 1].[DBO].[table1] order by DATE desc;

SELECT TOP 1 [DATE] FROM [database 2].[DBO].[table1] order by DATE desc;
```

Obviously, a `UNION ALL` on this is going to conflict with the `order by` clause.
Ultimately, I need each table sorted before selecting the first entry. Once the entry has been selected, I would like to combine all post-sort entries into a single result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could do the TOP query in the FROM clause (e.g. `SELECT [Date] FROM (SELECT TOP 1 [DATE]....) T UNION ALL....`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  You would basically want the tables showing up highest in the sort to have the lowest tblNumber.  Note that the sort is actually happening after the `union`, but it will achieve the exact same thing as long as the tblNumbers are correct.

```
select *  --if you don't want tblNumber returned, select all columns except tblNumber
from 
(
    SELECT 1 as tblNumber
    , [DATE] 
    FROM [database 1].[DBO].[table1] 
) tbl1
union all
(
    SELECT 2 as tblNumber
    , [DATE] 
    FROM [database 2].[DBO].[table1]
) tbl2

order by tblNumber, [DATE] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using parentheses?  Well, actually with a subquery:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM ((SELECT TOP 1 [DATE]
       FROM [database 1].[DBO].[table1]
       order by DATE desc
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 1 [DATE]
       FROM [database 2].[DBO].[table1]
       order by DATE desc
      )
     ) tt;
```

You can add an additional `order by` to the outer query, if you like.

Comment: This is it! This did exactly what I needed. Most appreciated!